# Laravel custom guard exclude routes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-5.8

I have created a custom auth guard for laravel 5.8 and is registered to the AuthServiceProvider.

Using the **constructor** definition below inside a **controller**, I want to exclude specific routes from getting authenticated (like register):

```
$this->middleware('protect', ['except' => 'store']);
```

**protect** is just an alias for the middleware doing the job

```
'protect' => \App\Http\Middleware\GauthJwt::class,
```

But this seems to have no effect as my guard gets hit anyway.

Do I have to somehow register or parse the routes in my guard?

Am I missing something on the way laravel handles custom guards?

Routes using this middleware:

```
| GET|HEAD | api/users                             | users.all                   | App\Http\Controllers\Api\User\UserController@all                        | api,protect |
| POST     | api/users                             | users.register              | App\Http\Controllers\Api\User\UserController@store                      | api         |
```

Comment: try this 
$this->middleware('protect', ['except' => ['store', 'anotherMethod']]);

Comment: Can you check in `php artisan route:list` what are the middleware attached to the route you are talking about and post here?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu updated with routes.

Comment: So, you want to escape `users.all`  route too?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu the users.register should be escaped but its not although you see the route does not contain the protect middleware.

Comment: @mallix that means it is already escaped, any error you are getting? have you tried `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan route:clear` and testing?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu yes. Probably the case is that the guard is running before reaching that constructor. Is that the case with laravel?

Comment: @mallix In that case if you will look into `Auth\` directory controllers that should not be working fine, there is something else, you are missing.

Comment: @mallix Can you try using `only` instead of `except` and lets see the result.